# JPA 2.1 / Hibernate - Joining 2 unrelated entities into the first one entity that has @OneToMany relation to third entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am sorry if the Subject was misleading but here is the scenario that I have.

```
@Entity
Class A {
@Id
private String id;
@OneToMany
private Set<B> b;
}

@Entity
Class B {
@Id
private String c;
private String d;
}

@Entity
Class C {
@Id
private String e;
private String f;
}
```

Currently, I am retrieving the entity **A** with its set of objects from Entity **B**. The thing is that Entity **B** and Entity **C** are not related by foreign key and they need to be joined by their primary keys, so when I retrieve the entity **A**, in the set of objects, I will get the columns from the entities **B** and **C** joined together.

Is there any way to tell Hibernate to join the columns from entities **B** and **C** when I try to get the object **A** ?

Answer (score 0):

In JPA 2.0 for joining related entities join is used. For this FK was needed.
Problem with joining unrelated entities is solved in JPA 2.1 standard, Hibernate 5.1 and above. You can use join on unrelated columns.